# Math operations for geometry_msgs/Vector3

Tags: eigen, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an IMU sensor mounted on my robot, but without properly aligned axes. To more get more easily processed data, I want to transform its output so the axes align. This is quite easily done with some calibration and usage of the dot product. However, there seem to be no math operations defined for Vector3 in geometry_msgs.

Is the proper way to do this to create a new vector of Eigen's format, do the calculations and then convert it back to Vector3? As I've understood there's no way to just cast between the types.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11575/math-operations-for-geometry_msgs/vector3/) by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 317 on 2011-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, there are no math operators for the message types. For many geometry messages there are [converter functions in TF](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/namespacetf.html). The resulting types are [typedefs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Overview/Data%20Types#Base_data_types_.28Quaternion.2C_Vector.2C_Point.2C_Pose.2C_Transform.29) to [bullet](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/main.html) types which have many math methods.
Here is [the conversion method for Vector3](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/namespacetf.html#e9c19270893b14223e2b2a8aeb2c48e7) and the according [bullet documentation](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtVector3.html).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) on 2011-10-17**:
OK, I see. Doesn't seem to be that different from using Eigen, but at least it's closer to being a built-in type in ROS. I might stick to using my own implementation of the needed operations for geometry_msgs::Vector3. Thanks!